# Find values in SQL with filter

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

I need to find usernumber who just have email address apart from gmail and yahoo.
Anyone having gmail and yahoo should be excluded from the list no mater if that usernumber has 3rd email apart from those 2.

```
select usernumber from list1 
where email not like '%gmail.com' and email not like '%yahoo.com';
```

I tried above but it does not filter that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function in `HAVING` to
judgement your logic.

```
SELECT usernumber 
FROM list1 
GROUP BY usernumber
HAVING 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN email like '%gmail.com' THEN 1 END) = 0
AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN email like '%yahoo.com' THEN 1 END) = 0
```